# Where is the proper place to put a file in a rails 2.3.8 project such that it extends the Object class, and doesn't mess up migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I've extended object to include these methods:

```
table_name
controller_name
name_singular
id_sym
name_as_symbol
human_name
human_name_singular
```

Now, initially, I had this in config/initializers. But That prevented me from running migrations (some weird naming issue, where instead of migrating to :table, it would migrate to :table.class.name.tabelize (which is what table_name does))

So... where do I put this file in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have a method named `table_name`.

change it to `db_table_name`, and you'll be fine.